# loading big csv file to redis

Tags: java, redis, nosql

I'm trying to load a csv file (this file has 27 millions rows) in redis DB, but it throws me an exception of `'redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out'`

My code:

```
   Jedis jedis = new Jedis();

    try {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        String line = in.readLine();
        int i =0;
        while (line != null) {
            try{
                String[] edgeDescription = line.split("\\s");
                if (edgeDescription.length >=0) {
                    jedis.hset( String.valueOf(i) ,edgeDescription[0],edgeDescription[1]);
                }
                i++;
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
            {

                e.getMessage();
            }


            line = in.readLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the set of information, it is difficult to answer this question. Though I will try to give you some points to check:

- Where do you state to which database to connect? I don't see any host/port spec. Can it be that in this case jedis instance tries to connect to `localhost:6379`?
- Is your code able to write some data to redis at all?
- If yes, can you introduce a counter and count how many lines are processed and how many lines are written to DB? After connection timeouts what happens with redis instance? Does it still run and everything is ok?
- Did you try `redis-cli -h host -p port monitor` command?

*A small remark:* your code in general is not efficient, you should use pipelines and process writes in chunks of 1000 writes or so, this will be much faster. Did you consider this?